# Dealing with corruption: file-level backup vs. pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, corruption

The [wiki on corruption](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption) recommends immediately taking a file-level backup of your database by stopping the postmaster and using `tar`, but I was under the impression that using `pg_basebackup` was a better option.  Is there any reason I shouldn't use `pg_basebackup`?

Comment: Stopping the engine and taking a file level backup is just another level of safety, if you can afford the downtime. It also ensures you can restore the database exactly as it was when you made the file copy. The more backups you have, the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pg_basebackup` and other methods like `pg_dump` might not actually finish due to the corruption, and you *really* need that backup in that case. Being independent of PostgreSQL and its tools, `tar` is not as likely to run into those issues.

In the case of corruption, that backup will be an invaluable insurance policy when you try to recover your data or do forensics, so playing it safe is always the best way to go.